# Switching audio between two clips By two buttons

Tags: button, audio, switching

I tried to put this code but the problem is that the second button does not

```js
     var button = document.getElementById("controls");
     var track1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
     var track2 = document.getElementById("audio2");

     button.onclick = function(){
       currTrackNo = this.innerHTML.replace(/Play track /, "");
       nextTrackNo = (currTrackNo == "1")? "2" : "1";
       this.innerHTML = "Play track " + nextTrackNo;

       if (currTrackNo == "1"){
         track1.play();
         track2.pause();
       } else {
         track2.play();
         track1.pause();
       }
     }
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Toggle sound clips</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio id="audio1" src="1.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="audio2" src="2.mp3"></audio>
    <button id="controls">Play track 1</button>
    <button id="controls">Play track 1</button>
```

I tried to put this code but the problem is that the second button does not

Answer (score 0):

Id for each tag should be unique. try changing the second buttons id to some thing else. Then get a reference to that button by its new id. After that set the proper action for the second button.
you may like to check the [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp) which explains more about id attribute.